# Safari modify suggested url

Tags: safari, ui

Imagine I visited a website: `http://example.com/food/cake.html` with the title *Delicious Cake*. When I use Safari and start typing *Del*, one of the suggestions shown by Safari might be the aforementioned website. If I hover over this site, my address bar will contain the title of the website: *Delicious Cake*. I can visit the site by pressing enter, but how do I get Safari to just fill the URL into my address bar?

For example, if I wanted to visit `http://example.com/food/`, I want the address bar to contain `http://example.com/food/cake.html` and then delete the `cake.html`.